# Gatsby.js with firebase-messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, gatsby

I'm developing a gatsby-pwa with inbuilt fcm. As I'm trying to initialize the messaging instance in my firebase.js file, I receive the error **WebpackError: ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined.**

```js
//firebase.js
import app from "gatsby-plugin-firebase-v9.0"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging"

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const messaging = getMessaging(app);
```

Interestingly enough, if I create a comment around the messaging const, I can build without problems or warnings. How can this happen if it doesn't happen with the db const as this is initialized perfectly?

Kind regards 
Tom

Comment: This is a known issue on some non-browser environments with the most recent release of the Firebase SDKs. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414517/209103) to the question I linked for more info, and a link to the Github [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6042) where it's being tracked

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with Firebase (and others third-party modules) and the cause of the issue is the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering). Where the code is being compiled in the Node server but targeting the web (using [`window` or other generated global objects](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/)).

You can bypass this issue by adding the following snippet in the `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
  stage,
  actions,
  getConfig
}) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      externals: getConfig().externals.concat(function(context, request, callback) {
        const regex = /^@?firebase(\/(.+))?/;
        if (regex.test(request)) {
          return callback(null, 'umd ' + request);
        }
        callback();
      })
    });
  }
};
```

Basically, this is excluding firebase from being bundled so they will be loaded by the client in the runtime, as it is requested.

Following the same approach, you can lazy-load or dynamically import Firebase with:

```
import('firebase').then(firebase => {
  firebase.initializeApp({ /* firebaseConfig goes here */});
  firebase.firestore().collection('someCollection').doc('someID').get()
    .then(doc => {
      // do stuff with Firestore data
    });
});
```

Have you considered using any service-worker like [`gatsby-plugin-firebase-messaging`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-firebase-messaging/).

Following your approach, it seems to be needed to handle Firebase message responses object like:

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Source: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/27726

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I found those solutions online as well and they work for me. But they suddenly stop working if I import anything from "firebase/messaging".

Comment: Does the dynamic import approach also fail? Have you considered using any service-worker? (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/27726)